# How change the driver used by MS Access 2010 x64 to connect to external ORACLE database

Tags: oracle, jdbc, database-connection, ms-access-2010

I want to know if is there a way of change the driver used by Microsoft Access to extract data (only use select like querys) from Oracle 9i data base.

The Access to Oracle connection is made using an external data source (linked table) and usually the default Access driver is ODBC for ORACLE, but I want to change that and use a JDBC driver for ORACLE instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The Access to Oracle connection is made using an external data source (linked table) and usually the default Access driver is ODBC for ORACLE, but I want to change that and use a JDBC driver for ORACLE instead.

I'm fairly certain that this is impossible. Access linked tables connect via Jet/ACE (for links to another Access database), or ODBC (for all other data sources). JDBC is not an option.

Comment: Do you know any way to query a ORACLE 9i Database from Microsoft Access x64 under Windows 7x64 using linked tables?

Comment: @user80024 The download page [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) appears to include some 64-bit Oracle ODBC drivers.